# Convergence and convolution...

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that for all $f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, $(f*g)(x) \rightarrow 0$ if $\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty$ with the assumption that  $g \rightarrow 0$ when $\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty$ and $g\in  L^1(\mathbb R)$. Thanks.

Comment: Suppose $g$ satisfies the hypotheses for $g$, and suppose that $\int g\,dx = 1$; let $f$ be identically $1$. Then it seems to me that $(f\star g)(x) = 1$ for all $x$.